# Howto set the action item selected state

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use the Sherlock actionbar library. I want to create a actionbar like this:
[image: Designed]

Two menu items on the right, and only one can be selected at one time (like a radio group).
My problem is, how can I keep selected state of menu item? Or can I set the menu item background programmatically?

I programmatically changed the menu item icon, like this:

[image: broken menubar]

Could anyone help me?

**Edit**
I'm using `menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_icon1)` to set the menu item icon. 
And the `drawable/actionbar_icon1.xml` is defined as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_selected_bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_icon1_img"></item>
</layer-list>
```

and `@drawable/actionbar_selected_bg` is defined like this:

```
<drawable name="actionbar_selected_bg">#0277ca</drawable>
```

`@drawable/actionbar_icon1_img` is an image.

This does not work, as the second picture shows.

Comment: handle the `MenuItem` click on `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` and change the layout according to the selection. You have the `setIcon(Icon icon)` method.

Comment: I use the `setIcon(Icon icon)` method, I got the result as picture 2. I want the icon's background fill actionbar's height.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the mistake the method is `setIcon(Drawable drawable)`,  and a drawable doesn't mean an image. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html

Comment: Yes, I use this `menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_icon1)` method, and the _drawable_ actionbar_icon1.xml shows in the **Edit** secton above. Would you please check it for me?